# Get view DataSource of GridControl in DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have gridControl with one gridView. In this gridView I can use inline search or column filter. How can I get elements in gridView(viewable DataSource) after filter and search?
This field return all elements in gridView without filters:

```
myGridView.DataSource
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop first for all active rows and than take the row cell value.

Here is an example code;

```
for(var i = 0; i < myGridView.DataRowCount; i++){
    myGridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "columnName");
}
```

Comment: How does it help me? myGridView.DataRowCount return me count of ALL rows without any filters applying. I just get all rows.

Comment: DataRowCount  returns only rows that was applied from the filter